# How to set the properties of a Spring prototype bean via Java configs?

Tags: java, spring

If I `@Autowire` the `BlahService` with `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` below, I get the `IllegalArgumentException` because `name` is null:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class BlahService {
   private String name;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init()
   {
      If (name == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
      }
   }

   private void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}

class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private BlahService service;
}
```

What's the proper way to ensure `name` gets set in `BlahService`?

Comment: You should share your config... Where you want to get the name from ?

Comment: @Betlista I want to set the name in my `@Configuration` class bean.

Comment: How are you even setting name? You cannot set it through constructor, there is no setter... So by what magic you are setting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, you have something like

```
@Bean
public BlahService getBlahService() {
    Blahservice bean = new BlahService();
    return bean;
}
```

and you have to modify it to

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public BlahService getBlahService() {
    Blahservice bean = new BlahService();
    bean.setName( findProperName() );
    retunrn bewn;
}
```

---

Full tests is:

**Main**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        BlahService bean1 = ac.getBean(BlahService.class);
        System.out.println(bean1.getName());

        BlahService bean2 = ac.getBean(BlahService.class);
        System.out.println(bean2.getName());

        FooService bean3 = ac.getBean(FooService.class);
        bean3.print();
    }
}
```

**BlahService**

```
package test;

public class BlahService {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**FooService**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    BlahService blahService;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("FooService#print: " + blahService.getName());
    }

}
```

**Config**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    static int counter = 0;

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public BlahService getBlahService() {
        BlahService bean = new BlahService();
        bean.setName("name" + counter++);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FooService getFooService () {
        return new FooService();
    }
}
```

executing Main#main prints:

```
name1
name2
FooService#print: name0
```

**edit (extended)**

**JUnit**

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    BlahService blahService;

    @Autowired
    FooService fooService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(blahService.getName());
        fooService.print();
    }

}
```

prints:

```
name1
FooService#print: name0
```

Comment: That's actually what I have but strangely code inside `getBlahService()` never gets called and `init()` is being called presumably because I have `@Autowired BlahService service` in `Foo`.

Comment: The code you provided works. But when I have the same setup as a Spring JUnit test or Spring Boot app, it fails. To see what I mean, add `@SpringBootApplication` to your `Main` class have it `implements CommandLineRunner ` and move your code in your `main()` method to Spring Boot's `public void run(String... strings) ` and you can see it fail.

Comment: Btw, my actual use case is using it in a `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` class. The SpringBoot description above is just another example to see it fail.

Comment: I added JUnit, please check.

Comment: I figured that my problem was having both `@Bean` `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` in the Config class *AND* having `@Component` `@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
` on `BlahService`.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer though because it does answer the question I'm asking; I just left out a detail in the quesiton.